# FontIcons what happens when I run out of "pageviews"?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

https://fonticons.com/ is a service to purchase customized font icons. example: `<i class="li li-like"></i>` Each plan specifies a limited number of Page Views.  And my immediate thought is: "What?"...  Do they literally just stop showing your icons unless you purchase a higher plan?  I suppose the answer to this question is "yes" but I'm just trying to be redundantly clear and I don't know where to ask.  It seems like they should elaborate a bit in the docs.  I apologize if this is the wrong section of StackExchange.
p.s. I understand the reasoning behind a pricing plan like this, bandwidth, CDN usage, etc.  FWIW, I assume the answer to my question is obvious, but not explicitly stated in their faq.  Maybe it shows a blank square, I don't know.

Comment: There are other free icons also available if you want try that http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Comment: @Deb I use fontawesome religiously and it's, well... awesome :)

Comment: If this question was asked by someone with a very large reputation, there would be a massacre of up-votes and answers.